# Connect DocuSign WebHook with http connection in sandbox

Tags: docusignapi

As I see in this article:
https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-adding-webhooks-application

that in Sandbox mode we can config webhook url with HTTP but when I go to my account Setting section it won't let me use HTTP

[image]

So my question is how can I use HTTP in sandbox mode for testing purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use HTTP with Connect

This guide explains it https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect-https-only

Quote from Q&A
"DocuSign Connect is used to transmit sensitive data about your envelopes across the Internet. As part of DocuSign’s focus on security, we are upgrading all notifications to use HTTPS only."

Hope this answer your question